# How to we copy docker container image of httpd to our local system?

Tags: docker

[Image of httpd copy to local system found error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYkBM.jpg)

I want to know where is the docker  image save and how we copy that image of httpd in local system?
I hope I will get my answer here!

Comment: As long as your local system already is on Linux, everything on your Docker container _already is_ on your local system. Sure, the filesystem might only be mounted in a process's private namespace, but you can mount it to the root namespace too easily enough. It's not clear what any of that has to do with gpg errors, though.

Comment: Note, though, that to be on-topic, a question needs to include everything needed to answer it **inside the question itself, as text**. Links don't count. Screenshots don't count. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) on [meta].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To the answer added by Chris, always check the docker hub's httpd image page for detailed information on the config and refer to the official docker documentation on the usage of docker commands.

httpd conf copy example steps:

```bash
~ docker pull httpd
Using default tag: latest 
latest: Pulling from library/httpd
fcdb9667c46b: Already exists
94864f1629dd: Already exists
25732f3fbbaf: Already exists
832bc635a9a3: Already exists
2c82a6b36c38: Already exists
Digest: sha256: f3e9eb9acace5bbc13c924293d2247a65bb59b8f062bcd98cd87ee4e18f86733
Status: Downloaded newer image for httpd:latest
docker.10/library/httpd:latest

~ docker run -d -p 8081:80 --name httpdtest httpd:latest
fd45446076b4900879e048c53a99c71c325db0c360c7de3407bbb73ea8ca4c9

~ docker cp httpdtest:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf httpdtest.conf

~ cat httpdtest.conf
#
# This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file. It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/> for detailed information.
# In particular, see
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directives.html>
# for a discussion of each configuration directive.
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do. They're here only as hints or reminders. If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.
#
# Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
...
```

[Click here for httpd docker image configuration.](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd)

Comment: This is a fair point, especially if this is not a one time thing but done as part of some automation script. (Question does not specify). For a quick peek though, I find just shelling into containers and `find` / `grep` for stuff to be a useful tool.

Comment: The reasons given to disallow screenshots of code given in [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) and https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode apply to answers too. Folks can't copy/paste from a screenshot; that screenshot often can't be read by screen readers and other accessibility tools, or indexed by search engines, or formatted into a font that works for the reader.

Comment: Thanks Charles. I wasn't aware of that. Updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Your command

```
docker cp <CONTAINER>:<SRC_PATH> <DEST_PATH>
```

*is* the correct way to copy contents out of a container to the host.

The issue is that the file that you are targetting here (`/etc/httpd/conf`) does not exist in the container. Maybe you meant the folder `/usr/local/apache2/conf` ?
You can inspect the contents of the container by shelling into it using

```bash
docker exec -it <CONTAINER> bash
```

Or using a dummy copy of the container:

```bash
docker run --rm -it httpd bash
```